# JQuery simple tooltip effect

Tags: jquery, html, css, tooltip

I have been trying to find a jquery tooltip effect but could not find what I need, so I have begun to write / modify the simplest / closest example. Clicking anywhere on the page should hide the currently open tooltip, unless a different tooltip is clicked in which case the currently open tooltip will be closed and the new one will be opened.

At the moment clicking anywhere on the page does nothing because there is a problem with the display of the tooltips. Clicking one tip displays it fine, clicking on the next closes the first and opens the second, but after this when another tooltip is clicked a blank box is displayed.

Why is this happening?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<script type='text/javascript' src='jquery-1.6.2.js'></script>

<style type='text/css'>
    .tooltip{ 
        display:none;
        padding:5px 10px;
        background-color:#e5f4fe;
        border:#5a5959 1px solid;
        position:absolute;
        z-index:9999;
        color:#0c0c0c;
        width:100px;
        height:50px;
    }

</style>

<script type='text/javascript'>
    $(window).load(function(){
    $(document).ready(function() {

    $('body').append('<div class="tooltip"><div class="tipBody"></div></div>'); 

    var tip;

    $('a[title]').click(function(e) {

        //display tip
        tip = $(this).attr('title'); // tip = this title   
        $(this).attr('title','');    // empty title
        $('.tooltip').fadeTo(300, 0.9).children('.tipBody').html( tip ); // fade tooltip and populate .tipBody

        //set position
        $('.tooltip').css('top',  e.pageY);
        $('.tooltip').css('left',  e.pageX);

     });

  });

});

</script>


</head>
<body>
     <a title="message1" class="printbtn" href="#">tip1</a>
    <a title="message2" class="printbtn" href="#">tip2</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add an event listener for a click to the body, using the event object, check the target if its your active tooltip, otherwise close the tooltip.

```
$('body').on('click', function (e) {
  if (!$(e.target).hasClass('tooltip')) {
     // hide your tooltip
  }
});
```

example: http://jsfiddle.net/xRNnP/

if you click anywhere the text will be hidden, if you click on the text itself nothing happens.

This can also be modified so that the target you are checking for is the link that triggers the tooltip, not the tooltip itself.